# How are node ids assigned in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

While writing basic Neo4j test cases for a simple relationship one of my test cases failed after changing the CREATE statement(s). The only difference in the result was the end node id changed from 1 to 20.

In the interest of understanding why I have to ask:

How are node ids assigned in Neo4j?

---

I am aware of: ([GitHub](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/3.5/community/graphdb-api/src/main/java/org/neo4j/graphdb/Node.java#L51))

```
 * A node's id is unique, but note the following: Neo4j reuses its internal ids
 * when nodes and relationships are deleted, which means it's bad practice to
 * refer to them this way. Instead, use application generated ids.
```

---

These statements result in the end node id for the relationship being `20`.

```
CREATE (n:Person { name:'John' }) RETURN COUNT(*)
CREATE (n:Person { name:'Mary' }) RETURN COUNT(*)
MATCH (a:Person),(b:Person) 
    WHERE a.name = 'John' 
    AND b.name = 'Mary' 
    CREATE (a)-[r:relationship_type]->(b) 
    RETURN COUNT(*)
```

This statement results in the end node id for the relationship being `1`.

```
CREATE (a:Person { name:'John' })-[r:relationship_type]->(b:Person { name:'Mary' }) RETURN COUNT(*)
```

---

EDIT

After leaning about [record_id_batch_size](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/3.5/community/kernel/src/main/java/org/neo4j/graphdb/factory/GraphDatabaseSettings.java#L794) from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53156754/1243762) and searching for related [test](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/search?q=record_id_batch_size&unscoped_q=record_id_batch_size) I tried this test that I thought would increment the ids by 2 instead of 1 as there are three different transactions which I expected each transaction to start a new batch of ids based on `record_id_batch_size`.

```
@Test
public void idBatchSize02MultipleTransactions() throws Throwable {

    try (ServerControls server = TestServerBuilders.newInProcessBuilder()
            .withConfig(GraphDatabaseSettings.record_id_batch_size, "2")
            .newServer()) {

        GraphDatabaseService graph = server.graph();

        Node node_001;
        Node node_002;
        Node node_003;

        try (Transaction tx = graph.beginTx()) {
            node_001 = graph.createNode();
            tx.success();
        }

        try (Transaction tx = graph.beginTx()) {
            node_002 = graph.createNode();
            tx.success();
        }

        try (Transaction tx = graph.beginTx()) {
            node_003 = graph.createNode();
            tx.success();
        }

        assertEquals(0L,node_001.getId());
        assertEquals(2L,node_002.getId());
        assertEquals(4L,node_003.getId());
    }
}
```

However the test fails because the ids are really `0L`, `1L`, `2L` and not `0L`, `2L` and `4L`. Will have to do more reading.

Comment: Of interest: public interface Node [Node](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/3.5/community/graphdb-api/src/main/java/org/neo4j/graphdb/Node.java#L55) extends Entity

Comment: Of interest: public class [NodeProxy](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/3.5/community/kernel/src/main/java/org/neo4j/kernel/impl/core/NodeProxy.java#L74) implements Node

Comment: Of interest: private Iterable<Node> [map2Nodes](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/3.5/community/kernel/src/main/java/org/neo4j/kernel/impl/coreapi/TxStateTransactionDataSnapshot.java#L361)( LongIterable ids )

Comment: Of interest: public Iterable<Node> [createdNodes()](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/3.5/community/kernel/src/main/java/org/neo4j/kernel/impl/coreapi/TxStateTransactionDataSnapshot.java#L361)

Comment: Of interest: // Returns nodes that have been added and removed in this tx. LongDiffSets [addedAndRemovedNodes()](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/91f5a3cf3dfb966888b190d06b11b7df81a3d839/community/kernel-api/src/main/java/org/neo4j/storageengine/api/txstate/ReadableTransactionState.java#L57);

Comment: Of interest: public static final Setting<Integer> [record_id_batch_size](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/da3a460a7e4481534a8e19b73b0c2c6ede973ae8/community/kernel/src/main/java/org/neo4j/graphdb/factory/GraphDatabaseSettings.java#L802) = buildSetting( "unsupported.dbms.record_id_batch_size", INTEGER,
            "20" ).constraint( range( 1, 1_000 ) ).build();

Comment: If someone wants a really interesting project to do with Neo4j they should put all of the code into a graph database and then run a query for the shortest path from [interface Node](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/3.5/community/graphdb-api/src/main/java/org/neo4j/graphdb/Node.java#L55) to [record_id_bacth_size](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/da3a460a7e4481534a8e19b73b0c2c6ede973ae8/community/kernel/src/main/java/org/neo4j/graphdb/factory/GraphDatabaseSettings.java#L802)

Comment: Of interest: record_id_batch_size changed in [test case](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/da3a460a7e4481534a8e19b73b0c2c6ede973ae8/community/community-it/kernel-it/src/test/java/org/neo4j/kernel/impl/api/index/IndexPopulationJobTest.java#L127)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The  node `id` depends of what you have previously created in your database.
It's mainly an auto-increment, except in some cases (ex: when we reuse ids, cluster, ...)

So how do you run your test ? 
Do you have a suit of tests and between each test you start a new database instance, or do you delete the database ?

Moreover, for each transaction, Neo4j reserved a batch of free id : 
https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/da3a460a7e4481534a8e19b73b0c2c6ede973ae8/community/kernel/src/main/java/org/neo4j/graphdb/factory/GraphDatabaseSettings.java#L794-L803

Comment: The reason I am not up-voting or accepting the answer is that it doesn't explain why the one node started out with and id of 20. The database was a new clean database with no existing nodes. What would be nice for an answer is a link to the source code on GitHub that shows where the ids are created and if that included the number 20 with a explanation in the code then I might find that acceptable. It has to be clear as to how the ids are created and leave me with no doubt on what an id will be if I create test.

Comment: I have updated my answer. But for my POV it's a bad idea to make a test assertion on something you don't have the hand on it and that can change in times (who know what will be the default value in next release...)

Comment: I know that, that is why I put the disclosure in the question. For the basic test which are always with a clean database and for each test instance the ids are stable so the test results are reproducible. If I do any deletes then I agree with what you state.

Comment: I will give you an up-vote for now. I am holding back on the accept because not only for me but for others the answer should show how the nodes are created from the batch ids you noted. I plan on running this down regardless as you seem to have found the other end of the code path and I have the start, now just to fill in the middle. If you don't put it in your answer I will put in my question as an update.

Comment: I created some test examples that modify the value for `record_id_batch_size` and still don't understand exactly when the id values will change. I have been reading up on sessions, transactions and commits however they don't talk about ids as is expected. Any way this will take me some time before I can give out an accept vote.

Comment: I gave the upvote because I haven't had time to get back to this to the level of detail I wanted, but your answer gave most of what I was seeking. If I need more detail I will ask a new question.